# TypeError: can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: numpy, neural-network, pytorch, pruning

I am using a [modified predict.py](https://gist.github.com/promach/186438ad7d2e6c1ec15d9ce5d8435c13/d1914a3f1da97f09ffc3ac095704b0bc9e6b2272#file-predict-py-L34-L53) for testing a [pruned SqueezeNet Model](https://gitlab.com/promach/Pruning-CNN/tree/master/SqueezeNet-Pruning)

```
[phung@archlinux SqueezeNet-Pruning]$ python predict.py --image 3_100.jpg --model model_prunned --num_class 2
prediction in progress
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “predict.py”, line 66, in
prediction = predict_image(imagepath)
File “predict.py”, line 52, in predict_image
index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
TypeError: can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
[phung@archlinux SqueezeNet-Pruning]$
```

I understand that numpy does not support GPU yet.

How shall I modify the code to get away from this error without invoking tensor copy data operation, `tensor.cpu()` ?

Answer (score 86):

Change

```
index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
```

to

```
index = output.cpu().data.numpy().argmax()
```

This means data is first moved to cpu and then converted to numpy array.

Answer (score 5):

I found out that I can just use

```
output.argmax()
```

Comment: I don't think that would give you numpy array. The output of that would be torch tensor

Comment: @UmangGupta

torch tensor is what I need. See the working example at https://gitlab.com/promach/Pruning-CNN/tree/master/SqueezeNet-Pruning

Comment: I was confused by the title of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `torch.max` function like follows:

```
value, index = torch.max(output,1)
```